# Suggestion for fields to use for this type of content

Tags: wygwam, grid, fieldtype, channel-fields, content-elements

I'm using EE 2.11.2, and am having trouble coming up with a good, user-friendly way to set up my fields to represent some dynamic content on a site I'm building. Can you offer a suggestion of a fieldtype to use, or some other scheme for making this content easily manageable?

So I have a channel called "Events", and two different events can have quite different 'Pricing' information. For example, here's an example of  complex pricing scheme for an event:

[image: Complex Example]

And here an example of a much simpler pricing scheme:
[image: Simpler Example]

What native or Add-On fieldtype(s) could I use to make this easily manageable content for an admin?

I have considered using a Grid field, with a 'heading' column, a 'left value' column, 'right value' column, and an 'info' column, such that if the admin filled out the 'Heading' column only, a heading would display, and the template would ignore the other three columns. If they fill out left and right value, it will display the line with the dotted lines betwixt the values, and if they filled out the info field, it would output that italicized grey text and ignore the other columns... But this scheme requires the admin to learn too much to use...

Any better ideas? Is there a field or combination of fields that can accomplish this easily? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Content Elements](https://fresh-dev.com/expressionengine/content-elements)? Create a new field type called "Event Pricing" selecting Content Elements as the field type, then when editing the field remove all the default ones, then add your own custom ones from the bottom, where you can type in the label and select the content type:

- "Pricing Header" (Header content type set to h3 for example)
- "Price" (Table Field - with 3 columns - see grab)
- "Note" (Rich Text field)

[image]

Then on the Publish Entry page the admin can choose from any of these 3 elements over and over again as required.

[image]

Comment: In the "Table" field, I don't see the options for "Prevent Column Changes" or "Enter Preset Labels...". I have the latest version of Content Elements. Is that a custom addition you made? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Latest version is v1.7.3. Please send a support request: https://fresh-dev.com/expressionengine/content-elements/support

Comment: Hi again Peter. I'm currently struggling with how to template this. The Content Elements docs only show how to loop through the cells using `{cells}<td>{value}</td>{/cells}`, not how to access a particular column...

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I figured out a way! We ended up moving pricing to the right, so I moved that column over, and this template code did the trick: http://pastebin.com/6Gm3rfyU